# Menu access problem in python language using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

When launching the application, I manage to reach the "Gérer carnets" menu and the python program continues. When I then try to reach the "Suivi des carnets" menu, I have the following error:

selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: The element reference of  is stale; either the element is no longer attached to the DOM, it is not in the current frame context, or the document has been refreshed

Could you, please, help me solve this problem ?

Regards

Python code :

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=resource_path('./driver/geckodriver.exe'))
action = ActionChains(browser)
browser.implicitly_wait(2)

# Go to application
browser.get("http://xxxxxx")

# Navigate to 'Gérer carnets'
firstLevelMenu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Gestion carnets')]")
action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Gérer carnets')]").click()

....

# Navigate to 'Suivi des carnets'
firstLevelMenu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Suivi activité')]")
action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform()
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Suivi des carnets')]").click()
```

Html Code :

```html
<div id="menu_detail">
  <dl>
    <dt onmouseover="javascript:montre('smenu3');">
      <a href="#" onfocus="javascript:montre('smenu3');">Suivi activité</a>
    </dt>
    <dd id="smenu3" onmouseover="javascript:montre('smenu3');" onmouseout="javascript:montre('');" style="display: block;">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="suiviactivite.do">Statistiques</a></li>
        <li><a href="suivicarnets.do">Suivi des carnets</a></li>
        <li><a href="rdvExport.do">Export des rdv</a></li>
      </ul>
    </dd>
  </dl>

  <dl>
    <dt onmouseover="javascript:montre('smenu4');">
      <a href="#" onfocus="javascript:montre('smenu4');">Gestion carnets</a>
    </dt>
      <dd id="smenu4" onmouseover="javascript:montre('smenu4');" onmouseout="javascript:montre('');" style="display: none;">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="carnet.do">Gérer carnets</a></li>
          <li><a href="blocage.do">Bloquer - Débloquer</a></li>
        </ul>
      </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
```

Comment: What line is actually erroring?

Comment: @DMart. Hello, It's the line with this code : action.move_to_element(firstLevelMenu).perform() with firstLevelMenu = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Suivi activité')]")

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why but it works when I add the line again:
action = ActionChains (browser)